# How to add dark theme in Adminer

Tags: mysql, darkmode, adminer

I am using the Adminer webtool to manage my MySQL databases. The Adminer is in the Basic Uxi which is full of white colour. While I am using the adminer at midnight time it becomes stressful for my eyes also, which leads to pain in midnight. The normal Uxi looks like this:

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sDxm.png)

Can anyone suggest me any dark theme for the adminer?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by adding a css file in your Adminer file in your computer.

First of all want to clone with this Repository if Your a GitHub user,by running this command :

```
git clone https://github.com/dracula/adminer.git
```

Then move the adminer.css file from Theme folder into adminer(In your computer) via Terminal If You are a **Linux** User:

```
cd adminer/

sudo cp -r theme/adminer.css /etc/adminer
```

Then Refresh the Adminer page it will be in dark theme with the CSS embaded in it.

If you are a **Windows** User :

- Copy the adminer.css from theme folder after cloning.
- go to etc
- go to apps
- go to adminer
- Paste the file in Adminer

**After all the process completed, in your computer:**

**It will be in ths dark mode with CSS embaded in it.**
[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sFF5.png)